# Sencha touch app adds translate3d values when you drag

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, transformation

I'm makign an app in Sencha touch 2.4.1. When I have it seems any Ext.Panel(grid, formpanel, tabpanel) child I can drag it around and it gets a translate3d value in style in debugger. When you drag the screen you get extra space on the left,top,bottom, right side of border, depends where you're dragging.

Here's a screen of the situation. Can anyone help out what setting/property to chnage so this thing will stop happening.

[image: translate3d added in panel when you drag]

Comment: Is it possible to see an example of this?

Comment: Example like how? in the upepr screen i have  grid but i can drag it's row around if the browser is minimized. As I do that i open a debugger and see that it automatically applies some transform values to the <element style="..."> If i tinker with css and do <i>transform:none </i> it doesnt' do anything.